# insert else update to a database the names of files in a specific directory using MVC3 and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, entity-framework-4.1

So, I'm fighting a migraine.  I cannot see the solution to this problem.

I have a table named dr405 that is preloaded with data.  My application only updates existing rows in the table with information.

I have a service method called `Save` in this save method I set the state in my context for the given `DR405` entity to modified and then call `SaveChanges`. This works as expected.

Now I'm trying to add in another step where I have a model called `DR405files` which is a child to `DR405` using a 1:N relationship.  I want to call a method `GetUploadedFiles()` that will check a directory thats name matches the dr405 primary key for files, then insert into the table `dr405files` the file names.

I've set up the relationships between the Models in both the classes and in the Database.  I've even written code that will correctly insert the filenames into `dr405files`.  However, after I run the application once, it throws an Null Reference exception in consecutive runs on `p`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
public void Save(DR405DBContext context, dr405 obj) 
        {
            obj.ModDate = DateTime.Now;

            context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;

            var uploadedFiles = this.GetUploadedFiles(obj.TangiblePropertyId);
                if (uploadedFiles !=null && uploadedFiles.Count > 0)
                {
                    uploadedFiles.ForEach(p=> {
                        var item = new dr405files { TangiblePropertyId = obj.TangiblePropertyId, FileName = p }; <---Exception Occurs here.
                    if(!obj.dr405files.Contains(item))
                    {
                        var fileItem = new dr405files { TangiblePropertyId = obj.TangiblePropertyId, FileName = p };
                        context.Entry(fileItem).State = fileItem.FileId == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                    });

                }           
            context.SaveChanges(); 

        }

public List<String> GetUploadedFiles(String id)
{
    var saveLocation = Path.Combine(DR405Service.SavePath + GetDR405ById(new DR405DBContext(), id).TangiblePropertyId);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(saveLocation);
    return Directory.GetFiles(saveLocation).ToList();
}

public class dr405files
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public String TangiblePropertyId { get; set; }
    public String FileName { get; set; }



}

public class dr405
{
    [Key]
    public String TangiblePropertyId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModDate { get; set; }
    public String PreparerName { get; set; }
...
}
```

Comment: Is there some code between Directory.CreateDirectory(saveLocation); and Directory.GetFiles(saveLocation).ToList() ? Are You sure You have files in this directory?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to keep it brief.  Like I said in my post it works the first time I run this.  The table dr405files gets a row created for each file in the directory.  The second run is when it fails.

Comment: Exactly what is null that causes the NRE to be thrown? p?

Comment: Yes. except I figured out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to load from obj.dr405files.  Which was not instantiated yet. I changed the code to pull from context.dr405files and....Voila!

```
    var uploadedFiles = this.GetUploadedFiles(obj.TangiblePropertyId);            
        if (uploadedFiles !=null && uploadedFiles.Count > 0)            
        {            
            uploadedFiles.ForEach(p=> {            
                var item = new dr405files { TangiblePropertyId = obj.TangiblePropertyId, FileName = p }; <---Exception Occurs here.            
            if(!obj.dr405files.Contains(item))
```

---

## New Code

```
    var uploadedFiles = this.GetUploadedFiles(obj.TangiblePropertyId);
        if (uploadedFiles !=null && uploadedFiles.Count > 0)
        {
            uploadedFiles.ForEach(p=> {
                var item = context.dr405files.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FileName  == p.Name && f.TangiblePropertyId == obj.TangiblePropertyId );
```